# How to use a Neural Network to classify a very large number/bit string?

Tags: neural-network, classification

How would I set up a NN to classify a cryptographic key for asymmetric cryptography, or generally a VERY large number/bit string?

I could split this bit string into bytes/16bit/32bit/64bit numbers to use as NN inputs, but that does not seem like a good idea, since I am not looking for relationships and patterns between the bytes or blocks. I am looking for structure in the whole key.

In this exact case I want to classify an almost 20000-bit string into 2 classes.

What would be the correct approach?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the key? How is it generated? And what are your two output classes?

Comment: The key pretty much looks like a random number, generated by multiplication of some random polynomials. I want to try to use the NN to detect whether an additional transformation was applied in the process of generation. Not sure if detectable at all, wanted to try.

Comment: Interesting question. Not sure if a NN is the best tool, but I would try the bits as binary input features to a dense network. 20k binary input features is not a big deal for modern hardware.

Comment: If you want to "detect whether an additional transformation was applied" could you describe the untransformed bit string? If it is effectively a random number already, and evenly distributed from all possible 20000-bit numbers as far as raw statistics can tell, then machine learning is unlikely to find anything. In general ML is the wrong tool to crack most cryptographic problems, at least on its own you will never crack any modern cipher that way.